# data is not passed into already created azure functions from logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

While doing the following steps in azure:

```
1.Created an azure function using function app.
2.In Logic App Designer flow, I have added the function app (w/o creating it via logic app)
```

I am not able to get the data from logic app in the created azure function.

Note: But after creating the azure function via logic app flow , I can able to get the data that passed from LApp.

SS of Logic App [image]

Azure function name:

Thanks,
Sathiyarajan M

**Sample functionApp code:**

```
module.exports = function (context, data) {

  var inputDocVal = data.inputdbval[0].rgValues.name
  var resname = data.resourceGN
  var input = [];
inputDocVal.push(resname)
  // Response of the function to be used later.
  context.res = {   
    body: {        
   "name":inputDocVal
    }
  };
  context.done();

};
```

**Error I received as follows:**

```
2017-05-17T15:03:27.611 Exception while executing function: Functions.docdb. mscorlib: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at module.exports (D:\home\site\wwwroot\docdb\index.js:3:36)
    at D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\1.0.10947\bin\azurefunctions\functions.js:93:24.
```

Comment: Compare the working and not working functions and you might see the reason. Hard to help you without seeing that.

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by "data is not passed"? The function gets called but doesn't receive the right parameters? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: yeah @david Ebbo, function got called but doesnot receive the right parametes.

Comment: Please update your question with more details. E.g. get a minimal repro case and paste the complete function code and function.json.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Added some more inputs, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might also want to compare the Logic App versions, the problem might be related to how you are sending the parameters in each version. To compare the versions, go to Development Tools >> Versions and compare how you are sending the params in the working and non-working versions.